# Footer is messed up when defining the viewport on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, viewport

Trying to make our wordpress theme responsive, starting off by adding

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

within the header's head tags, and it has this effect on the footer...

any way of sorting this out? thank you in advance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not make site resposnive adding viewport to head of it.

Try with using media queries:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

AND you can use framework such as bootstrap:

https://getbootstrap.com/

You can add this code to additional CSS for now

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#footer {
  float: left;
  background: url(images/footer.jpg) 50% 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#footer p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b5b5b5;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
}
```

Comment: what this does is loading the website zoomed in on mobile (adding the viewport thing only squizes the footer logos on the bottom left again) will have alook on the links you've sent... thank you so much for replying